# What is the Regex expression to transform a serialized C# tuple into PropertyName: value?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-7.0

If you take a tuple `(string MyProperty, objet MyValue)` and serialize it you end up with `{"Item1": "MyProperty", "Item2": <value>}` whereas what you really want is `{"MyProperty": <value>}`

Can someone please help me with the proper Regex expression to convert these two back and forth?

Comment: It looks like what you really want is a KeyValuePair, not a tuple. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I can do differently, and I did actually, but the question is really about the regex here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should demonstrate converting to and back. Note that to escape " in strings, you use 2 of them.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex tupleRegex = new Regex(@"{""Item1"": ("".+?""), ""Item2"": (.+?)}");
string tupleString = @"{""Item1"": ""MyProperty"", ""Item2"": <value>}";
string tupleToKeyValuePairResult = tupleRegex.Replace(tupleString, "{$1: $2}");
Console.WriteLine(tupleToKeyValuePairResult);

Regex kvpRegex = new Regex(@"{("".+?""): (.+?)}");
string kvpToTupleResult = kvpRegex.Replace(tupleToKeyValuePairResult, @"{""Item1"": $1, ""Item2"": $2}");
Console.WriteLine(kvpToTupleResult);
```

see it in action: https://repl.it/repls/SquigglyPricklyFormula